# How do I style to react-select styles props

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm wondering now how to set the style simply.
I just want to set the margins.
I've read the react-style docs and this is so complicated.
Covering the component itself with a div tag and setting margins solves the problem, but it's a bit unsmooth.
How can I write it in one line?
Please let me know if you have any ideas.

react select official docs
https://react-select.com/home#custom-styles

```
<Select
  instanceId="selectbox"
  options={DisplayColumnsData}
  defaultValue={DisplayColumnsData[0]}
  styles={?????}
/>
```

thank you

Comment: `How can I write it in one line?` easy answer, you can't. You need to write your custom styling following their object typing.

Comment: oh, Im waiting update. thank you